# Change the variable name for facet_wrap, label_both

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a question about changing the label name for facet_wrap. When using `facet_wrap(~`Spine Condition`, labeller = label_both`, I just obtained "Spine Condition: Both good" not "spine: Both good" as an example.

I just tried to change the column name from "Spine Condition" to "spine" but it failed. I do not understand it.

Could you please help me with it?

Thanks so much. Attached here are what I have obtain from the previous code

```
facet_wrap(~ `Spine Condition`, labeller = label_both
```

and the error when trying to change the variable name.

[image: enter image description he[enter image description here]
[image: re]

Comment: I want to obtain "spine: Both Good", "spine: One Worn/Broken", "spine: Both Worn/Broken"

Comment: Please provide your code and a sample dataset.

Comment: Put the code to rename the line where you start your plot, i.e. before making `g1`. Otherwise `g1` will contain the original dataframe with the original column name. That's why ggplot2 is complaining that it can't find your renamed column `spine` in the dataset.

Comment: Can you post the entire code for the plot (`ggplot()` line too)?  Also, we need to see what the dataset looks like, since it seems `ggplot` can't find `spine` as a column name in your dataset.

Comment: This problem has been solved and I just took the suggestion to placing the rename ahead of g1. Thanks so much for your all kind help.